# Automatically delete files in storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

So I've noticed that whenever I do a machine learning train/retrain ([from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/retrain-machine-learning-model)), it generates a lot of files in my Azure blob storage as shown here

[image: Screenshot]

I wanted to ask if it was possible to automatically delete all these files or prevent them from ever being generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automatically delete all these files in blob storage, you can use the [Lifecycle Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts#azure-portal-list-view) of blob storage.

It's easy to set up a rule and filter, after the rule is set up, all the files will be deleted as per the rule you defined.

Simple steps:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> Blob services -> Lifecycle Management, then click "Add rule".

[image]

2.In the "Action set" tab, select Delete blob and fill in the textbox; Then in "Filter set" tab, select a path.

[image]

For more details/instructions, please follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts#azure-portal-list-view).

Also note that the rule runs once per day, and for the first time, it may take 24 hours to take effect.

Comment: I didn't see "Lifecycle management" option in the storage Is it because I created the storage via the "Machine Learning Studio" setup? Is it possible to make "Lifecycle management" visible"?

Comment: @AlexFeng what's your storage account type? GPv2 or Blob storage accounts? or others?

Comment: @AlexFeng, please see the [supported storage account type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts#storage-account-support) for life management, if it does not support, you can consider upgrade it to the proper one.

Comment: I just upgraded, and I see it now. Is it also possible to prevent certain files from being deleted?

Comment: @AlexFeng There is a filter set, but can only apply to a container or container/directory. If it does not meet your need, you can consider write a code with azure function/webjob, then you can keep/delete files you need.